# How to get cookies in http post

Tags: ajax, http, post, cookies, http-headers

I'm quite new in http servlet. My objective is to

**get cookies from browser 
 and do a store cookies:username**

in redis when it do post request to my API endpoint. So that next time it calls my API it doesn't have to pass username to me just the cookies so i can link it(cookies) to that specific username.

My problem is that **I can't get cookies from the browser even thought I set it**.

Here's my javascript ajax `(document.cookie = "testcookie=1234567890; max-age=3600";)`

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        document.cookie = "testcookie=1234567890; max-age=3600";
        var coin = $.trim($('#coin').val());
        var username = $.trim($('#username').val());
        var usern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$/;

        $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost:9086/api/v1/ms/wxpay/wxpayorder',
            method: "POST",
            data:JSON.stringify({username:username,coin:parseInt(coin)}),
      dataType:'json',
      contentType: 'application/json'
        }).done(function(data){
            loading.hide();
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));return;
      data = data.data;
            if(data.success) {
        //alert("success");
        jsApiCall(data.jsApiParameters);
            } else {
                weui.alert('服务端错误，请刷新重试或联系客服');
            }

        });
    });
```

Here's my API post endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/wxpayorder")
@CrossOrigin
fun createOrder(
                response: HttpServletResponse,
                request: ServletRequest,
                response2: HttpServletRequest,
                @RequestBody req: WxPay
): String{


    val cookies = "testcook"
}
```

the reason i said i cant get it it's that i tried to search all the attributes inside the response(HttpServletResponse), request(ServletRequest), response2(HttpServletRequest), the Cookies Value is null or -1(getHeaderNames).

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax request has an absolute URL, and your server-side code has `@CrossOrigin`. It is, therefore, reasonable to assume that you are making a cross-origin Ajax request.

- Your HTML page is loaded from `http://example.com`.
- Your code, `document.cookie = "testcookie=1234567890; max-age=3600";` will set a cookie for **example.com**
- Your request, to `http://localhost:9086/api/v1/ms/wxpay/wxpayorder` won't include that cookie because it is not a request to example.com.

There is no way for your code, on example.com, to set a cookie for localhost:9086. If it were possible, then that would be a serious security risk.

Find some other way to transfer the information that does not involve cookies.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I wanna ask that what you mean is that, if the origin in the web-browser is `localhost` then i will be able to pass the cookies? if yes, then must it be `localhost:9086` or can be other port also can?